# Convert NSData To UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

First of all I am selecting some images in one listingstep1view and passing those UIImages other View Controller by using `sharedInstance`.

**ListingStep1Viewcontroller**:

```
- (void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


    for (UIView *v in [_scrollView subviews]) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }

    NSLog(@"info :%@", info);

    CGRect workingFrame = _scrollView.frame;
    workingFrame.origin.x = 0;

    NSMutableArray *tempArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[info count]];

    for (int i =0; i<info.count; i++) {

        NSDictionary *dict = [info objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] == ALAssetTypePhoto){

            if ([dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage])
            {

                UIImage* image = [dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

                [iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate load_uploadingImage:[image fixOrientation]];

                NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate get_upload_image], 1.0f);
                //NSString *encodedImage = [data base64Encoding];
                 [Base64 initialize];
                self.convertedImage=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
          //self.convertedImage=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
        NSLog(@"converted Data To Image= %@",self.convertedImage);

              NSString *strEncoded = [Base64 encode:data];
 strEncoded = [strEncoded stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
               [tempArray addObject:strEncoded];

                [images addObject:image];

                UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
                [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
                imageview.frame = workingFrame;
                [_scrollView addSubview:imageview];
                workingFrame.origin.x = workingFrame.origin.x + workingFrame.size.width;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = %@", dict);
            }
        }
        else if ([dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] == ALAssetTypeVideo){

            if ([dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]){
                UIImage* image=[dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

                [images addObject:image];

                UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
                [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
                imageview.frame = workingFrame;

                [_scrollView addSubview:imageview];

                workingFrame.origin.x = workingFrame.origin.x + workingFrame.size.width;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = %@", dict);
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Uknown asset type");
        }
    }

    self.chosenImages = images;



    [[ListingStep2Model sharedInstance]setImagesAssetArray:tempArray];
    //[[ListingStep2Model sharedInstance]setConvertedImage:self.convertedImage.image];

    [_scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(workingFrame.origin.x, workingFrame.size.height)];


}
```

**ListingStep5viewcontoller:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < [[[ListingStep2Model sharedInstance] imagesAssetArray]count]; i++) {

       NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[[[ListingStep2Model sharedInstance] imagesAssetArray]count]];

              //UIImage*imageTodata=[[ListingStep2Model sharedInstance] convertedImage];

     NSLog(@"Data Imges:%@", [[[ListingStep2Model sharedInstance] imagesAssetArray] objectAtIndex:i]);
        //NSLog(@"Data Imges:%@", imageTodata);

        NSDictionary *dict;


        if ([dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] == ALAssetTypePhoto){

            if ([dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage])
            {
              {
                    UIImage* image = [dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

                    [iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate load_uploadingImage:[image fixOrientation]];

                    NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate get_upload_image], 1.0f);
                                        //UIImageView *imgv = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

                    [Base64 initialize];
                     NSString *strEncoded = [Base64 encode:data];

  strEncoded = [strEncoded stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];

                    NSMutableDictionary *param = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                    [param setObject:strEncoded forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d",i]];

              }

                } else {
                    NSLog(@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = %@", dict);
                }
            }
        }
     [iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate startIndicator];

    NSMutableArray *totalrequest = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [totalrequest addObject:param];

    [RequestAndResponseHandlers helparucommonRequestAndResponseHandlerWithParam:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:totalrequest,@"request",nil] methodName:methodName completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *response) {

        NSLog(@"Response :%@", response);

        if ([[response valueForKeyPath:@"response.httpCode"] integerValue]==200) {
          [[iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate appdelegate] navigateTo:[iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate publicView ]];
        }
        else {
            [iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate alertWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please try again!"];
        }

        [iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate stopIndicator];

        [self.containerTbl reloadData];
    }];

}
```

**Output** is in `NSData` Format:

```
4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAJgAAAAAAA6ABAAMAAAABAAEAAKACAAQAAAABAAAEcKADAAQAAAABAAAC9gAAAAD/7QA4UGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAAA4QklNBCUAAAAAABDUHYzZjwCyBOmACZjs%2BEJ%2B/8AAEQgC9gRwAwERAAIRAQMRAf/EAB8AAAEFAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC//EALUQAAIBAwMCBAMFBQQEAAABfQECAwAEEQUSITFBBhNRYQcicRQygZGhCCNCscEVUtHwJDNicoIJChYXGBkaJSYnKCkqNDU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6g4SFhoeIiYqSk5SVlpeYmZqio6Slpqeoqaqys7S1tre4ubrCw8TFxsfIycrS09TV1tfY2drh4uPk5ebn6Onq8fLz9PX29/j5%2Bv/EAB8BAAMBAQEBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC//EALURAAIBAgQEAwQHBQQEAAECdwABAgMRBAUhMQYSQVEHYXETIjKBCBRCkaGxwQkjM1LwFWJy0QoWJDThJfEXGBkaJicoKSo1Njc4OTpDREVGR0hJSlNUVVZXWFlaY2RlZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoKDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZ
```

Comment: `imge = [UIImage imageWithData:imgdata];`. please search for same questions before asking.

Comment: Thaxq for the respons ,But when iam passing same Nsdataformate is going to come plz ones check my code n help me...

Comment: ya i have serched alote but finally my hope on this stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to change the Base64string to NSData and then you can easily convert to UIImage. Here are the steps:

(1) Convert Base64String to NSData using the [NSData+Base64 files](http://projectswithlove.com/projects/NSData_Base64.zip).

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:originalString];
```

(2) Now you can convert the NSData to Image as follows:

```
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: If you don't want to use third party base 64 libraries, you can use the native `initWithBase64EncodedString:options:` method.